# What is the meaning of =~ in Perl?

Tags: perl, operators

What does `=~` mean in Perl? Further, what does `+=` mean? What are these called in Perl?  i.e. "special characters", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all languages these are called "operators". 
The operator =~ in perl is called "binding operator". 
I found some [good explanation](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node87.html) on some site.

Answer (score 5):

`=~` is the [Binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators).

`+=` is an [Assignment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators).

The Perl documentation can explain them better than I can: `perldoc perlop`